# Get most frequent array inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Problem:**

I wish to get the array that is most reoccuring inside a multidimensional array. Google was not helpful this time around.

**Sample array:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [iata] => HAV
            [lat] => 22.9892
            [lng] => -82.4091
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [iata] => PEK
            [lat] => 40.0801
            [lng] => 116.585
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [iata] => HAV
            [lat] => 22.9892
            [lng] => -82.4091
        )
)
```

**Desired output:**

```
Array
(
    [iata] => HAV
    [lat] => 22.9892
    [lng] => -82.4091
)
```

Comment: By `iata` key or any key?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte By `iata` key. That should have been in my description, sorry about that.

Comment: Even if other values are different? Or you want to compare all values and see which array is the most frequent?

Comment: Yes, even if other values are different. IATA codes are always unique so I won't have a problem down the road with comparing this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$count  = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'iata'));
arsort($count);
$result = array_column($array, null, 'iata')[key($count)];
```

- Get an array of the `iata` values and count those values
- Sort them descending (preserving keys)
- Get an array of the arrays indexed by `iata` value (they will be unique) and get the one with the key of the highest `iata` count value